# Is changing a listview's ArrayList an appropriate use of static?

Tags: java, android, listview

I am making two activities, one main page with a customlistview of tasks and on that main page you can click and on "+" and add a new task. It will redirect you to the addTask activity, which is a form with a button that calls submit_task_to_list.

MainActivity

```
static KittyAdapter mAdapter; // Could be listview adapter
static ArrayList<Tasks> tasks = new ArrayList<Tasks>();
```

AddTaskActivity, when a button is clicked

```
public void submit_task_to_list(View v) {
    EditText title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Title);
    EditText desc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Description);
    Tasks newTask = new Tasks(title.toString(), desc.toString());
    TaskCentral.tasks.add(newTask);
    TaskCentral.mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Is there a better solution to do this than use the static keyword? I have previously overused static and it was painful to take care of as my other app became more complex. I want to minimize bad habits on this app.

I have tried to move the onClickListener to the mainactivity but android can't find it.

Full code:
The main activity

```
public class TaskCentral extends Activity {

    static KittyAdapter mAdapter; // Could be listview adapter
    static ArrayList<Tasks> tasks = new ArrayList<Tasks>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task_central);

        String[] tString = {"Hi", "My", "name", "is", "Kitty"};
        Tasks T1 = new Tasks("m", "p");
        Tasks T2 = new Tasks("m", "p");
        Tasks T3 = new Tasks("m", "p");
        Tasks T4 = new Tasks("m", "p");
        tasks.add(T1);
        tasks.add(T2);
        tasks.add(T3);
        Tasks[] TaskArr = new Tasks[tasks.size()];
        TaskArr = tasks.toArray(TaskArr);

        ListView taskCentral = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Central);
        mAdapter = new KittyAdapter(this, TaskArr);
        taskCentral.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        // mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_task_central, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
public void addNew(View v) {
    Intent addTaskIntent = new Intent(this, AddTaskActivity.class);
    startActivity(addTaskIntent);
}
```

}

My Adapter

public class KittyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
public KittyAdapter(Context context, Tasks[] items) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_task_layout, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater myinf = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = myinf.inflate(R.layout.custom_task_layout, parent, false);

    Tasks singleTask = getItem(position);
    CheckBox done = (CheckBox) customView.findViewById(R.id.Done);
    TextView myItemText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.ItemText);

    myItemText.setText(singleTask.getTitle());

    return customView;
}
```

How to add item and notifydatasetchanged from the second activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I would do:

In TaskCentral:

```
final static int REQUEST_CODE_ADD_TASK = 324234;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ADD_TASK:
                String title = data.getStringExtra("title");
                String desc = data.getStringExtra("desc");
                Tasks newTask = new Tasks(title, desc);
                tasks.add(newTask);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

and launch AddTaskActivity like:

```
public void addNew(View v) {
    Intent addTaskIntent = new Intent(this, AddTaskActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(addTaskIntent, REQUEST_CODE_ADD_TASK);
}
```

and in AddTaskActivity where ever you finish (onClickListener?):

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.putExtra("title", title.toString());
intent.putExtra("desc", desc.toString());
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! One thing, is there a way to also add to the ArrayList `Tasks`?  It used to be `TaskCentral.tasks.add(newTask);` (right above the old notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: sure, see my answer now

Comment: Oh pff silly me. Thank you so much for your help! I'll definitely use this

Answer (score 0):

The usage of static methods or variables can be a good or a bad solution depending on your project. You have to know what they are and how to use them, then you will know when to use them. Static methods and variables belong to the class and are created first, instance methods and variables can only be referenced by using an instance of the class - in other words: they belong to the object.

Comment: this is a very general answer. It doesn't address the question

Comment: If you understand this then you will know when something gets available to be used or not. The situation here seems to be related to bad coding due to a lack of knowledge about this. I may be wrong too, but for a better answer I will need to see the code for the event listener and know where each of the methods are located.

Comment: The question is very clear. It's also clear that he knows more or less those things you explained in your answer. IMHO he's looking for a "best practice"

Comment: @goncalopinto Yeah that's my bad, I should make it more clear that I'm familiar with the concept of static, it's just that I jump to it a lot. It seems like there should be a way to make arrayadapter accessible only within my class but there seems to be a lot of trouble, because it's a very basic thing to do. I'll update with more info